# Getting User Input from TextField

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm new to swift language and xcode, and I've been stuck on this problem for weeks.

How can I get user input (from a textField) and turn it into a variable that I can use in my code?

Thank you.

Comment: It is the text field's `text`.

Comment: A quick Google search and you would have found the complete documentation including attributes of the UI components - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfield

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is:

```
let userInput = textField.text
```

Make sure you place the code inside of the function that is called when the user is finished editing.

For example, if you have a confirm button, you would probably want to initialize this variable inside of the function that is called when the user taps the confirm button.